# Set-Cookie HTTP header with subdomains

Tags: api, jwt, subdomain, setcookie, httpcookie

the set-cookie topic is really confusing for me and so far I haven't found any matching use case...

I'd like to have a **backend** running on

a) api.example.com

and the **frontend** might be running on

b) admin.example.de/login

**or**

c) example.de/admin/login

When the user wants login on b) or c) he will use the api of a).

For b) and c) I managed that the browser sets the HTTP cookie...  But somehow he never uses it for any requests on a).

Is b) or c) possible?

Domains like "api.example.de", ".example.de", "example.de" didn't work for me..

[image]